# Buffer around lines with varying width in between

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, buffer, voronoi-thiessen

My questions is about creating an elongated buffer around various lines and these buffers should run right in the middle of two parallel lines. The problem is that the lines do not have an equal width at all points.
[image: image showing the lines around which the buffer should be placed]

To give some more context, different weed control measures were used in different lanes, so I want to visualise the lanes as polygons/buffers so I can use them to extract data from different lanes/treatments.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create "buffers" along the mid line between irregularily spaced lines, create voronoi polygons:

1. [Densify](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#densify-by-interval) lines and [Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisextractvertices).
2. Create [voronoi polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#voronoi-polygons) for the densified points
3. Join the line id to the voronoi polygons, using [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with this expression `overlay_intersects ('line',$id)[0]`
4. [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) voronoi polygons based on line id (see screenshot 1)
5. To clip the large buffers at the margin, collect all lines in a multiline, buffer this and intersect it with the voronoi polygons (see screenshot 2 for the result). You can do this e.g. with this expression using [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression):

   ```
   intersection (
      $geometry, 
      buffer (collect_geometries (overlay_nearest ('line', $geometry)),15)
   )
   ```

- change the value of `15` for buffer size at the end of line 3
- change `line` with the name of your line layer

*Screenshot 1, red: initial lines; blue with black dashed lines: buffers (one buffer in yellow is selected):*
[image]

*Screenshot 2:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Babel, I manged to get the polygons. Still working on getting the edges right but your beautiful and visual explanation has helped a lot. I only did not manage to create voronoi polygons from a densified line (because Qgis told me it wanted points as input) so I used the ''points along geometry'' to transfer the line into points and create a buffer from that.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I skipped one step: extract vertices, see updated answer

Comment: You made my day Babel! thanx

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot it seems that the length of all parallel lines are equal but the width spacing between them is not uniform. In such a case, to find a centerline programatically, you can

1. Resample your polylines at regular interval for eg. 1 point / meter to
   obtain uniform sampling rate across all polylines
2. Next find midpoints of line segments connecting every N-th point pair of adjacent polylines
3. Create a line connecting all midpoints obtained in step 2 for each adjacent pair of lines to obtain centerline between each adjacent pair of lines

Another option is to create a raster of a polygon created by every adjacent set of line and then use something a [skeletonization algorithm](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html) to find a centerline and convert that raster skeleton back to vector representation.

Edit:

You can also skeletonize the polygons created by adjacent lines directly, without converting them to rasters using [Polygonal Skeletons](https://scikit-geometry.github.io/scikit-geometry/skeleton.html)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment, one previous answer solved my question.... but I did not know the method you described but it can be very useful in other projects!